# disable encode html in activeform field dropdown yii2

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

How can disable `encode html` in `ActiveForm::Dropdown` active form Yii2?

I want to create a `select html tag` that shows multilevel data so that children make fixed padding than its parents. So, I create an array like this:

```
$items = [
   'Computer'
   '   Hardware'
   '   Software',
   '      Programming'
   '&nbps; C#'
];
```

But `space` is removed and `&nbps;` encoded and both not worked. We can use pure html tag, but how can create it using Yii2::ActiveField?
Note that we can encode items before calling widget based on our conditions.

There is any idea?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retain the spaces,

```
echo $form->field($model, 'attribute')->dropDownList($data, [
    'encodeSpaces' => true,
]);
```